# How to set a relative path for Qt dlls when releasing a Qt project?

Tags: windows, qt, dll, dynamic, path

When I release my `Qt` project, I want to redistribute the `QtCore4.dll` and `QtGui4.dll` files with my project, but not in the same directory as my `.exe` (in some other relative path).

How can I make my `.exe` find them automatically?

I also don't want to set the `%PATH%` or any other environment variable in my customer's environment.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the safest way is to launch your application using a script that *does* change the `PATH` (but only for that session) before launching your application. Here is a script I use to launch a custom version of `Qt Creator`:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\qt474_custom_msvc2008_x64\lib;C:\Qt\jom
start C:\Qt\qtcreator231__custom_msvc2008_x64\bin\qtcreator.exe
```

I think there are alternatives, like [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but (just like `rpath` on *nix), they introduce other problems. Either side-by-side dlls or a change in the PATH seems to be the most stable solution.

Also, did you mean that you want to deploy the debug versions (QtCore***d***4.dll, etc.) of those dlls? That would be pretty unusual--make sure you use the release versions. (Unless, of course, you have a valid reason for using the debug versions.)

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your last paragraph, I didn't mean the **d** versions, I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should reconsider not changing the `PATH` in your customer's environment: many projects/applications do that, so you should consider that as a real option.

Second, the best way of doing this seems to be by editing a `qt.conf` file placed in the same folder as your executable. See [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) for more information about editing an qt.conf file.